# Path location of rbenv and MacPorts

Tags: python, ruby, unix, macports, rbenv

I have been using python for months & I have python & git installed on a Mac via **MacPorts** in **bash_login** @ export PATH="opt/local/bin:/opt/local/bin/mysql5/bin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

Today I wanted to try ruby so I installed Rbenv & ruby 1.9.2-p290 via ruby-build. It created a path in **bash_profile** @ PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

When I echo $PATH in the terminal my path is now set to:/Users/demet8/.rbenv/shims:/Users/demet8/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

I am no longer able to use my python/git/ because my system is reading Usr/local/ first in the bash_profile (file).

**Question**: I need opt/local/ to read first so I can still use python/git. Should I eliminate the **bash_profile** (file) rbenv created & consolidate rbenv's path into my **bash_login** path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consolidate all paths in your bash_profile file. The macports path and rbenv are distinct and can be pulled together without conflict of order.

I use both Macports, Python and Rbenv & Ruby.

My consolidated path looks like this:

```
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:
/Users/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:
/Users/user1/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
....
```

You could have it like this:

```
PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Great! so would my path now look something like this in bash_profile:export PATH="opt/local/bin:/opt/local/bin/mysql5/bin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin:/usr/local/bin:/$HOME/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

eval "$(rbenv init -)"

Comment: @demet8: Added to my answer. Always add path separately. So that you know their purpose later on.